# Android launch activity on top of particular activity

Tags: android, android-activity, back-stack

Say, I have below Activity

```
Activity A, Activity B, Activity C and Activity D
```

Currently stack is having below Entry

```
Activity C
Activity B
Activity A
```

I have to launch `Activity D` so that stack become like below,

```
Activity D
Activity A
```

What flag I have to set?

Comment: From which activity you wanted to call Activity D?

Comment: @Shiva From Activity C

Comment: I Assuming you are calling Activity A -> Activity B -> Activity C -> Activity D.

If this flow, set the intent flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP to the intents which you are calling for Activity B and Activity C. Such that in Activity stack will contain only Activity A and Activity D.

Comment: Try once, not 100% sure

Comment: @Shiva that doesn't work. Setting `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` will not change any of this behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using `A` as a dispatcher. When you want to launch `D` from `C` and finish `C` and `B` in the process, do this in `C`:

```
// Launch A (our dispatcher)
Intent intent = new Intent(this, A.class);
// Setting CLEAR_TOP ensures that all other activities on top of A will be finished
//  and setting SINGLE_TOP ensures that a new instance of A will not
//  be created (the existing instance will be reused and onNewIntent() will be called)
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
// Add an extra telling A that it should launch D
intent.putExtra("startD", true);
startActivity(intent);
```

in `A.onNewIntent()` do this:

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    if (intent.hasExtra("startD")) {
        // Need to start D from here
        startActivity(new Intent(this, D.class));
    }
}
```

Comment: In this way we have to launch Activity-A unnecessary. I am not looking for any workaround instead a modular flag to do it.

Comment: There are no flags to do this. You aren't launching activity A unnecessarily. Activity A is already running. You are just gong back to activity A and telling it to start the activity for you.

Comment: This isn't a "workaround". This is a proper navigation pattern. There are others navigation paterns your could use. But you cannot do this using Intent flags.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this ?

```
<activity name="Activity D"
   android:allowTaskReparenting="true"
   android:taskAffinity="Activity A" >
```

Comment: Did you try it? Because this doesn't work. This has nothing to do with tasks and task reparenting. All activities are running in the same task.